# Stablize a value in c++

Tags: c++, math, modulus

I have a  variable which is a Modulus of Congruence x=y(mod 360),which means y varies from 0 - 360 and if the value is greater than 360 it again comes to 0. For example x=5 for y = 365 .

I wrote this function to stabilize y , so if the difference between x and previousx is greater than 5 then i get x otherwise previousx .

```
float stabilize(float x,float previous){

    if(fabs(x-previousx)<5)
    {
        return previousx;
    }
    else
    {
        return x;
    }

}
```

This works fine between 0 to 360 But this fails on the boundary condition of 360 and 0 .How can i stabilize the value when y is a value near 0 such as 0.3 and previous y is near 360 such as 359. So the difference calculated here is 359 - .3 = 358.7 . but i want it to be the modulo 360 difference which is 1.3 .

Comment: So you want the absolute value of the angle difference between `x` and `y`?

Comment: no , i am already taking the absolute value using fabs .

Comment: Okay, now I'm very confused about what the question is. So you already have a difference, but you want to normalize it to something like `[0,360)`? Can you give us examples of your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: ok , the input is always mod 360 . For example the inputs to the function, x = 358 and previousx = 2 , i want the output to be previousx and if x = 356 and previousx = 3 i want the output to be 356 .

Comment: The variables names might be creating the confusion , i have edited question to make the question more clearer .

Comment: Oh okay, you're just trying to test if the angle between `x` and `previousx` is less than `5`. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11498248/922184) has an `angleDiff()` function that will give you the difference between any two angles. The result is normalized to `[-180, 180)`. So that might do what you want.

Comment: Okay , will try it out .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like `if(fabs(x-previousx)<5 || fabs(x-previousx)>355)`? Given that the input data is mod 360, if the difference is big enough it means that both values are close enough to the border.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this should not work . I will try it out , thanks .

Comment: You might consider using a "while" to make this approach correct for numbers above 720 and below 360...

Comment: But in this question the input numbers are always between 0 and 360, so let's keep it simple

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract the original numbers and take modulo 360 of the fabs(result):

for example:

```
359 - 720.3 = -361.3
fabs(-361.3) = 361.3
361.3 % 360 = 1.3
```

Comment: I have no way of getting the original numbers , i am using a external library for getting the angles .